# Convert a String into an Integer starting with 0

Tags: java, string

I have to convert from Strings the first 2 characters into an int.
The problem is when a string starts with 09 that it get converted in 1 and the year looks like 2001 and not 2009.

this is what I have, maybe there are better methods ...

```
String s = longString.substring(0, 2); // 09asdasdas
int jahr = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Comment: I don't get that error. Try this example:  
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String longString = "09asdasdas";
  String s = longString.substring(0, 2); // 09asdasdas
     int jahr = Integer.parseInt(s);
     System.out.println(jahr);
 }
}

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense and I am unable to reproduce the supposed error.  Please provide a more complete example, including what you think the output _should_ be.

Answer (score 2):

> ...and the year looks like 2001 and not 2009...

Not entirely sure I get your question, but it may depend on how you print it. The following code prints a leading 0 if necessary:

```
String longString = "09asdasdas";
String s = longString.substring(0, 2); 
int jahr = Integer.parseInt(s);
System.out.printf("Year 20%02d.", jahr);  // prints "2009"
```

Compare with this snippet

```
String longString = "59asdasdas";         // <-- Changed to "59....."
String s = longString.substring(0, 2); 
int jahr = Integer.parseInt(s);
System.out.printf("Year 20%02d.", jahr);  // prints "2059"
```

(Here is an [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/Vdc5Z).)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to get rid of the leading 0, but if you want to, here's one way to do it...

Here's how to get rid of the leading 0 if any and it will work fine for any number from "00" to "99" (which your question and substring(0,2) seems to imply):

```
Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2).replaceAll("^[0]", ""));
```

Comment: And cue in all the clueless *"omg you're using regexp, now you've got two problems"* ;)

Comment: What's the reason for having the `[``]` around the `0`?

Comment: @aioobe: oh it's just an habit, that way I don't run into issue when the character I'm using has a reserved meaning for the regexp parser.  Say *replaceAll("^$", "")* instead of "^[$]".  Saved my a** so many times I tend to use it a lot (especially useful when you programmatically create regexp'es with characters to match that are not known in advance, which I've done from Bash scripts).  It's really just an habit and it cannot hurt (at least I don't think so).

Comment: Aha, hehe. On the other hand I accidentally used the character class `[.]` to represent "any character" once here on SO :-) let's say I didn't get upvoted for it hehe ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a leading zero for decimal manipulation. Bad practise, because it can be interpreted as an octal number. You're also mentioning years. If you're trying to manipulate dates, then don't use ints. Use a library like [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). I assume you need something like:

```
String string = "09asdasdas";
String dateString = string.substring(0, 2);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YY");
DateTime date = formatter.parseDateTime(dateString);  
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your best bet is probably to check the first character and if 0, trim it and then send to Integrer.parseInt() - if I remember correctly, Integer.parseInt doesn't like a number of factors (leading 0s, being among them) I'd just remove it.

Comment: I don't believe `parseInt` has any problems with leading zeros.